# Is it possible to split frame accurate an AAC file using FFmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, aac

What I did:

```
# create source material
ffmpeg -y -i some.file -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -b:a 128k -ar 44100 source.m4a

# split into two parts 
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:00 -i source.m4a -to 6 -c copy part1.m4a
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:06 -i source.m4a -c copy part2.m4a

# re-encode only the first part with the same setting as source file
fmpeg -y -i part1.m4a -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he -b:a 128k -ar 44100 part1reencoded.m4a

# create file list to be concatenated
echo 'ffconcat version 1.0
file part1reencoded.m4a
file part2.m4a' > my.list

# finally concatenate both parts
ffmpeg -y -f concat -safe 0 -i my.list -c copy parts.m4a

# play the result
ffplay parts.m4a
```

Unfortunately, the result file has noises at `00:00:06`.

Is it possible to split frame accurate an AAC file using FFmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

You can split frame accurately, at 44100, every frame is 23 milliseconds.

What you can’t do is concatenate aac from different encodes.